# Перенос текста из activity в поисковую строку браузера телефона

Tags: java, android

Я новичок в программировании, мне нужно при нажатии на кнопку открыть браузер телефона, перейти в гугл и ввести текст и TextView в поисковую строку. Всё получается, кроме последнего( Подскажите как это реализовать (хотя бы наводку, где искать то, что нужно).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String escapedQuery = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/#q=" + escapedQuery);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: А всё оказывается так просто, спасибо ))